# How to avoid retries while the shutting down the application in camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have an application that calls external service and in case of connection errors, application retries for certain number of times.

There are certain instances where the application had to be shutdown on receipt of SIGTERM; During the shutdown process, camel waits for the in-flight messages to be completed which is good but odd times with connection errors, the retry also kicks in causing long delays for shutdown. is there a way to stop the retries while application is shutting down?

Per this [link](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Stopping-long-redelivery-on-Camel-shutdown-td5714773.html) from the year 2012, Graceful shutdown was made aggressive after timeout but seems it is not any more with v2.24.0.